# Math in compiled pdf has different encodings for different compiler. When are no unicode characters used?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode-math, font-encodings

When selecting and copying math in the compiled pdf I noticed it isn't always matching the original symbols.
There are three different scenarios I can remember. Two of which I was able to reproduce:

1. Everything matches. Summations are translated to a Sigma, though it is a different character as `\Sigma` (∑ vs Σ). I was able to get this result when compiling with XeLaTeX.
2. Most thing match. Greek symbols are copied as the closes unicode character but summation signs are "X", `\prod` = "Y", `\int` = "Z". As far as I've noticed this happens if pdfLatex is used. If the same source is compiled with e.g. xelatex it results in case 1 again.
3. Almost nothing matches. Only ascii symbols like "x" and so on match. Even greek letters are translated as "p" or something else. This is the case I was not able to reproduce but I remember being annoyed that some documents I got for university had this flaw.

My question is, what are the reasons for these different cases? Are there more? How can I reproduce case 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the cause are missing or faulty tounicode values in the pdf. It can happen easily with pdflatex as the math fonts predate unicode. With lualatex + xelatex you get the best result if you use the unicode-math package and a proper math font.